# storing reference arrays in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have several arrays that will never change.

```
Gender ( 'M' => trans('core.male'), 
    'F' => trans('core.female'), 
    'X' => trans('core.mixt')


Grades (...the same, with 20 grades that will never change)
AgeCategory (...the same, with 5 categories that will never change)
```

Now, I wouldn't like to store it in db, because it will never change, I could store it locally, to avoid useless queries.

But I need to access it with both Laravel and Javascript (VueJs)

How should I do it, not to duplicate code.

I could write all of it in the server once, and then call Web Services, but I think it will increase significantly connections, it might not be the good path...

Any Idea how should I manage this situation?

Answer (score 0):

You can create same dictionary class (and an interface for it) and hold it this data like this:

```
// base dictionary
abstract class BaseDictionary 
{
    protected $data = [];

    protected $translatedList = null;

    public function get($key, $default = null) {
        $value = array_get($this->data, $key, $default);
        if ($value != $default) {
            return trans($value);
        }
        return $value;
    }

    public function getList()
    {
        if (is_null($this->translatedList)) {
            $this->translatedList = [];
            foreach ($this->data as $key => $value) {
                $this->translatedList[$key] = trans($value);
            }
        }
        return $this->translatedList;
    }
}
```

and add just a concret dictionary definition:

```
class Gender extends BaseDictionary 
{
    protected $data = [
        'M' => 'core.male',
        'F' => 'core.female',
        'X' => 'core.mixt'
    ];
}
```

You can also bind it in your service provider as a singleton:

`\App::singleton(Gender::class)`

After that the calls will looks like:

`app(Gender::class)->get('F');`

that was for translation. And for the whole list:

`app(Gender::class)->getList();`